# Retrieving a value inside a python dictionary, that is inside a dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

I have the following json that I converted into a dictionary. Now I want to save the href values into a variable.

```
{
 "request_id":"9838-25be1f8e6e57",
 "message":"Validation request submitted.",
 "links":[
   {
     "href":"/v1/app/validate/status/9838-25be1f8e6e57",
     "rel":"status"
    },
    {
     "href":"/v1/app/report/9838-25be1f8e6e57",
     "rel":"report"
    }
 ]
}

apiLinks=dict(response.json())
for links in apiLinks['links']:
     print(links['href'])
```

The following code does print out the href values alone but I want to know how to access them so I can store them into variables. I am aware that dictionaries in python have a .get function but I can't seem to get right.

Thank you

Comment: `href_list = [elem['href'] for elem in response.json['links']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list and append the values to that list instead of printing them:

```
links_list = []
for links in apiLinks['links']:
    link_list.append(links['href'])
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists